# Hi, I am new to magento, I want to generate a Coupon, which would work only if the cart amount is say 200 bucks

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon-codes

I have tried setting the rule but did'nt get to work. The condition that I want is , cart amount should me minimum of 2000 INR.

Comment: What happens when you try? is the price not updating or is there an error?

Comment: When I apply the Coupon , its says this coupon is not valid..

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer this link carefully.
http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html

After Create Rule You can Save and Apply.
Also Reindex and Clear cache..it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps to create Coupon code.

You can do this by doing the following when creating a Shopping Cart Price Rule:

Rule Information tab:

a) Rule Name

b) select Status

c) Select Websites

d) Customer Groups

e) Select Coupon: Specific Coupon

f) Add your coupon code

g) 'Uses per Coupon' field as per your requirement

h) 'Uses per Customer' field as per your requirement

i) 'From date' & 'to Date': you can leave blank if you want always apply this coupon on the cart.

Conditions tab:

If ALL of these conditions are TRUE:

a) click + then select cart attribute "Subtotal"

If Subtotal equals or greater than 200 in cart matching ALL of these conditions:

Coupon code will be applied when cart subtotal is equaled or greater than 200.

Hope, it will be helpful.